# Lookup values in access with criteria

Tags: ms-access

i have an access database with a series of values concerning bicycle tracks: date, participants, count of participations, distance of the tracks... after a few years there a lots of data. now i'm trying to find a way to lookup when a participant has done 1000km. (date and in which tracknumber). something like:

count KM from Participant A and look when he reached 1000km.
he had in race 25 966KM and in race 26 1009KM.

and then show in a report: participant A crossed the line of 1000Km on date x and in race 26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a table `Races` with the fields `ParticipantID`, `RaceID`, `Distance` and `RaceDate`, this should be yours:

```sql
Select
    Races1000.ParticipantID,
    First(Races1000.RaceID) As RaceID,
    First(Races1000.RaceDate) As RaceDate,
    First(Races1000.DistanceSum) As DistanceSum
From
    (
        Select
            Races.*,
            (
                Select
                    Sum(Distance)
                From
                    [Races] As S
                Where
                    S.RaceDate <= Races.RaceDate And
                    S.ParticipantID = Races.ParticipantID
            ) As DistanceSum
        From
            Races
        Where
            (
                Select
                    Sum(Distance)
                From
                    [Races] As S
                Where
                    S.RaceDate <= Races.RaceDate And
                    S.ParticipantID = Races.ParticipantID
            ) >= 1000
    ) As Races1000
Group By
    Races1000.ParticipantID
Order By
    Races1000.ParticipantID,
    First(Races1000.RaceDate),
    First(Races1000.DistanceSum)
```

If you have such a table, create a query with the provided SQL statement to see if it is working for you.
Or just adapt the table- and fieldnames to your names.

Edit:

To create a report based on that saved query, select the query in the database window and press `Report` in the tab `Create` of the RibbonBar. It will create a standard report based on the selected query:

[image]

Regarding your question about "2000, 3000, ... KM limits" you can change `>= 1000` to `>= [KM]` to be able to use the same query and report for any distance limit. When opening the query you will be asked for the distance and you can enter it.

Comment: can you help me a little bit more? 
i created a tbl with the fields and then a form based upon that table.
where do i put the code.(button?)

how can i add an appendix?

Comment: What button? What appendix? Maybe you edit your question and add more details of what you need.

Comment: i'm a beginner. so i do not exactly know what you mean, therefore my question how to add a database as example/appendix. i try to have a result of that code when clicking a buton on the form.

Comment: Didn't you create a query with the query (the select...) I provided? That would be the first step to let you see the result of the SQL statement. Until now there is no form involved.

Comment: can you advice me how to do that (wizard?...)

Comment: Take a look here how to create a query: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-queries-a9739a09-d3ff-4f36-8ac3-5760249fb65c You would need a `select query`. Create one and switch to it's SQL view and overwrite the content with the query I provided.

Comment: Run the save query (you can open it like a table). Does it show what you need?

Comment: yes it works. now i need to show it (report?) as i discribed in my question.  must i do it in the same way for all distances (2000, 3000km....) or is there an other way. PS sorry but i have not enough reputations to chat

Comment: I edited my answer regarding how to create a report based on a query.

Comment: Edited once more regarding 2000,3000 question.